# How to draw Line graph using data from MySQL table and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to draw line graph using data from database.

http://futurk.com/futurk.com/etkin/pages/veri.php
This link is show me what i have in my database.
Here is veri.php code:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'futurk_etkin');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'etkin');
define('DB_NAME', 'futurk_etkin');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT id,gerilim,akim,guc FROM etkin");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);


?>
```

I also made linegraph.html file that i can see my graph. Here is linegraph.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ChartJS - LineGraph</title>
        <style>
            .chart-container {
                width: 640px;
                height: auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="chart-container">
            <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
        </div>
        
        <!-- javascript -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/js/Chart.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/js/linegraph.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I added a linegraph.js. Here is my linegraph.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://futurk.com/futurk.com/etkin/pages/veri.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){
            console.log(data);

            var id = [];
            var gerilim = [];
            var akim = [];
            var guc = [];

            for(var i in data) {
                id.push("ID " + data[i].id);
                gerilim.push(data[i].gerilim);
                akim.push(data[i].akim);
                guc.push(data[i].guc);
            }

            var chartdata = {
                labels: userid,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "gerilim",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                        data: facebook_follower
                    },
                    {
                        label: "akim",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                        data: twitter_follower
                    },
                    {
                        label: "guc",
                        fill: false,
                        lineTension: 0.1,
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                        data: googleplus_follower
                    }
                ]
            };

            var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

            var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartdata
            });
        },
        error : function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

but when i click this link, I see nothing.Am I wrong?

http://futurk.com/futurk.com/etkin/pages/charts/linegraph.html

Comment: Check the console, there's erorrs.

Answer (score 0):

Make type as POST and add datatype as json. And make label as id instead userId,I hope it will work for you. i have suggested change in the code.

Looking at your encoded JSON,

```
{"saat":"0","KayitTarihi":"2016-11-24 00:00:57","Gerilim":"0.2","Akim":"0.01","Guc":"0.001"}
```

It seems you have just copy-pasted code from someone else, since your JSON does not have any `"id"`. So first of all correct your query in the php file (`linegraph.js` code) like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url : "http://futurk.com/futurk.com/etkin/pages/veri.php",
    type : "POST",
    datatype: 'json',

    success : function(data){
        console.log(data);

        var saat = [];
        var Gerilim = [];
        var Akim = [];
        var Guc = [];

        for(var i in data) {
            id.push("ID " + data[i].saat);
            Gerilim.push(data[i].Gerilim);
            Akim.push(data[i].Akim);
            Guc.push(data[i].Guc);
        }

        var chartdata = {
            labels: saat,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Gerilim",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
                    data: Gerilim
                },
                {
                    label: "Akim",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
                    data: Akim
                },
                {
                    label: "Guc",
                    fill: false,
                    lineTension: 0.1,
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                    pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
                    data: Guc
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

        var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: chartdata
        });
    },
    error : function(data) {

    }
});
});
```